# Hibernate Criteria unable to retrieve collection of a nested object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have got a `TeamPlayer` object with a `Player` object as on of its attribute. The `Player` object has `One-to-Many` relation with `PlayerSuspension`.

When I try to retrieve all `TeamPlayers` and fetch all player's suspensions along with. It throws following error. Could you help me out where's the issue?

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ps of: we.data.weref.model.TeamPlayer
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1770)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.NullExpression.toSqlString(NullExpression.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.LogicalExpression.toSqlString(LogicalExpression.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.LogicalExpression.toSqlString(LogicalExpression.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at we.data.weref.dao.hbn.TeamDaoHbn.getTeamPlayers(TeamDaoHbn.java:109)
    at we.data.weref.service.impl.TeamServiceImpl.getTeamPlayers(TeamServiceImpl.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.getTeamPlayers(Unknown Source)
    at we.data.weref.controller.api.TeamControllerApi.getTeamPlayers(TeamControllerApi.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DigestAuthenticationFilter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My hibernate criteria is as following

```
    return getSession()
           .createCriteria(TeamPlayer.class, "tp")
           .createAlias("player.playerSuspensions", "ps", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
             .add(Restrictions.and(
                 Restrictions.or(
                     Restrictions.isNull("ps"),
                     Restrictions.eq("ps.team.id", teamId)
                 ),
                 Restrictions.eq("tp.team.id", teamId)
            )
        )
        .list();


        @Entity
        public class TeamPlayer {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Integer id;

            @ManyToOne
            @JsonSerialize(using = IdSerializer.class)
            private Team team;

            @ManyToOne
            @JsonSerialize(using = IdFirstNameLastNameSerializer.class)
            private Player player;

            public Integer getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            public Player getPlayer() {
                return player;
            }
            public void setPlayer(Player player) {
                this.player = player;
            }
                public Team getTeam() {
                return team;
            }
            public void setTeam(Team team) {
                this.team = team;
            }
        }

    @Entity
    public class Player implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5688361063269574977L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
        private List<PlayerSuspension> playerSuspensions;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
      }

@Entity

public class PlayerSuspension implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Player player;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne                          // if competition == null then player is suspended from all the competitions
    private Competition competition;    // if competition given then only from that particular competition

    private Date startDate;
    private Integer games;
    private Integer weeks;
    private Integer gamesSpent;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ps` is an alias. You should specify a property name of `PlayerSuspension`. For an example `ps.name`.

You can use something like this (you can convert it to criteria). Maybe, it can be more simply

```
from TeamPlayer teamPlayer 
    left join teamPlayer.player player 
    left join player.playerSuspensions suspension
where suspension.team.id = :teamId 
    or not exists (select innerTeamPlayer.id from TeamPlayer innerTeamPlayer 
            inner join innerTeamPlayer.player innerPlayer 
            inner join innerPlayer.playerSuspensions
            where innerTeamPlayer.id = teamPlayer.id)
```

**Update**

You can't use `TeamPlayer.getPlayerSuspension()` with result of this HQL. Because of collections are lazy by default. You can try to fetch `playerSuspensions` by HQL with `left join fetch`

```
from TeamPlayer teamPlayer 
    left join teamPlayer.player player 
    left join fetch player.playerSuspensions suspension
where suspension.team.id = :teamId 
    or not exists (select innerTeamPlayer.id from TeamPlayer innerTeamPlayer 
            inner join innerTeamPlayer.player innerPlayer 
            inner join innerPlayer.playerSuspensions
            where innerTeamPlayer.id = teamPlayer.id)
```

or you can change a mapping

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "player")
private List<PlayerSuspension> playerSuspensions;
```

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve all TeamPlayers where Player object (inside TeamPlayer) has empty/null suspensions also. But in case of inner join, hibernate doesn't retrieve TeamPlayers where a Player object has got null/empty Suspensions.

Comment: @AlamHussain Please, add your persistent classes to the question and describe in detail what you want to retrieve.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying and providing me with the answer. I really appreciate it. 
I tested your answer and it came with following exception 
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: we.data.weref.model.Player.playerSuspensions,

Comment: @AlamHussain Is HQL correct?  I update my answer in consideration, that it is correct and you get a result.

Comment: Just a little update in HQL as followed but ended up in the error I mentioned above. 
  return getSession().createQuery(
From TeamPlayer teamPlayer 
  left join teamPlayer.player player 
  left join player.playerSuspensions suspension 
 where suspension.team.id = :teamId 
      or not exists (select innerTeamPlayer 
                      from TeamPlayer innerTeamPlayer 
           inner join innerTeamPlayer.player innerPlayer 
                     inner join innerPlayer.playerSuspensions 
                    where innerTeamPlayer.id = teamPlayer.id)
   .setParameter("teamId", teamId)
  .list()

Comment: FetchType.EAGER is not suitable as Player table is retrieved through a lot of other services and they don't need suspension details of Players.

Comment: @AlamHussain You shouldn't do this `select innerTeamPlayer `, you can use `select innerTeamPlayer.id`. I don't understand, do you get any TeamPlayer by HQL or not, because of an error is not a result of a HQL execution.

Comment: I made it select innerTeamPlayer as it was throwing an error over "*".

Comment: @AlamHussain Ok. Use `innerTeamPlayer.id` or use `count(*)` with `where 0 =()`